# Can't get my simple Docker Slate app to work properly with volumes

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am maintaining a [slate](https://github.com/slatedocs/slate) app to host our API documentation, it is a simple static site.

On the setup we have now, it is painful to work on it, since every change requires an entire project build (docker-compose build) to see it in live, when you are writing it.

However I am struggling to understand the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose` for this app in order to make it easier to work, and see changes live, when you refresh the browser.

Current `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:2.6-slim AS builder

WORKDIR /srv/slate

COPY .ruby-version .
COPY Gemfile .
COPY Gemfile.lock .

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        git \
        nodejs \
    && gem install bundler -v 2.4.22 \
    && bundle install \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY . /srv/slate

RUN chmod +x /srv/slate/slate.sh

RUN /srv/slate/slate.sh build

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=builder /srv/slate/build/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
COPY --from=builder /srv/slate/build/fonts/* /usr/share/nginx/html/fonts/
COPY --from=builder /srv/slate/build/images/* /usr/share/nginx/html/images/
COPY --from=builder /srv/slate/build/javascripts/* /usr/share/nginx/html/javascripts/
COPY --from=builder /srv/slate/build/stylesheets/* /usr/share/nginx/html/stylesheets/

EXPOSE 80
```

Current `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'

x-app_image: &app_image
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image: comp/comp-api:0.0.1
  networks:
    - comp-dev
  tmpfs:
    - /tmp

services:
  runner:
    <<: *app_image
    command: /bin/bash
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    profiles:
      - runner
  web:
    <<: *app_image
    command: ["serve"]
    ports:
      # nginx is listening on port `80`
      - 4567:80

networks:
  comp-dev:
    external: true
```

I already found some workarounds, like, modifying the `docker-compose.yml` to use volumes, in order for the container to actually "see" the changes to the files as they happen. replacing my image with the official one, and running the command `serve` to start middleman when the container go up and changing my ports, Everything just works then.

```
    image: slatedocs/slate
    command: ["serve"]
    volumes:
      - ./source:/srv/slate/source
    ports:
      - 4567:4567
```

However I feel like this is not the appropriate change, since it would change too much the app we deploy today. Since we have some shenanigans with `nginx` on this app.

Anything I am missing on my current setup, that would get me the same results as my workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your multistage Docker build is ultimately running an Nginx server against static files.  The build stage isn't part of the final image, and nothing is watching to restart or rebuild anything if files change.

Comment: @DavidMaze, yeah that is correct. Thanks for your time! 
That is what I see in the container logs when it is up. a bunch of nginx log messages. Is there any way to setup a rebuild if something in the `/source` folder changes? are volumes a viable option here?

Comment: Volumes just assign persistent storage to a container.  Very recent versions of Compose have a [watch](https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/) functionality that could potentially do this rebuild.

Comment: Didnt know about watch at all. Will try It! Thanks @DavidMaze